# Start and Stop Button on Python Tkinter window

Tags: python, python-2.7, button, tkinter

I have created a start button as well as the stop button. After I press the start button, it runs a python program. The stop does not work until I terminate the Python code. What should I do? Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import Tkinter, tkMessageBox, time

Freq = 2500
Dur = 150

top = Tkinter.Tk()
top.title('MapAwareness')
top.geometry('200x100') # Size 200, 200

def start():
    import os
    os.system("python test.py")


def stop():
    print ("Stop")
    top.destroy()

startButton = Tkinter.Button(top, height=2, width=20, text ="Start", 
command = start)
stopButton = Tkinter.Button(top, height=2, width=20, text ="Stop", 
command = stop)

startButton.pack()
stopButton.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

These are the 2 functions I am using. I have then created a start and stop button.

Comment: What is your `top` variable?

Comment: The Toplevel widget is used to display extra application windows, dialogs, and other “pop-up” windows. top = Tkinter.Tk()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the stop button does not work until you close the program is because `os.system` blocks the calling program (it runs test.py in the foreground). Since you're calling it from a GUI that needs an active event loop, your program is hung until the test.py program completes. The solution is to use the `subprocess.Popen` command, which will run the test.py process in the background. The following should enable you to press the stop button after starting test.py.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import Tkinter, time
from subprocess import Popen

Freq = 2500
Dur = 150

top = Tkinter.Tk()
top.title('MapAwareness')
top.geometry('200x100') # Size 200, 200

def start():
    import os
#    os.system("python test.py")
    Popen(["python", "test.py"])


def stop():
    print ("Stop")
    top.destroy()

startButton = Tkinter.Button(top, height=2, width=20, text ="Start", 
command = start)
stopButton = Tkinter.Button(top, height=2, width=20, text ="Stop", 
command = stop)

startButton.pack()
stopButton.pack()
top.mainloop()
```